# Detecting touch sprites and convertToNodeSpaceAR

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a really hard time getting something as simple as detecting touch on a sprite to work... Can anybody help? I'm trying to create a method as a category for CCSprite that given a point or touch will return YES if the point is within the sprite, NO if it isn't.

At the moment I have one implementation that seems to work when the sprite is not part of a cropped texture from Zwoptex (ie. the image used for sprite was not trimmed)

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];
CGRect spriteRect = self.textureRect;
spriteRect.origin = ccpAdd(ccpSub(self.positionInPixels, self.anchorPointInPixels), self.offsetPositionInPixels);
return CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, point);
```

I have found though that this does not work if the sprite was trimmed in the original texture. This variation seemed to do the trick

```
CGRect spriteRect = self.textureRect;
spriteRect.origin = ccpAdd(self.offsetPositionInPixels, self.positionInPixels);
return CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch]);
```

But now I have another set of sprites from a frame cache that do not seem to like this! They are trimmed and I can't see any difference from the sprites used with the code above. Can someone shed some light on the meaning of convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:? I'm sure the problem lies in my ignorance and that there is a common elegant way of doing this in the Cocos2d framework...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `CGRectContainsPoint();`. I was having the same issue for a while and I suspect that the rect and the points we were comparing were not translated to the same point system yielding negative results.

Solutions:

1. Make a method / define that can correctly convert the point systems between each other.
2. What I did: Create a grid class that tracks a sprites position on the grid and translate touches to the points on the grid.

Option 1 may make more sense for your needs, but I needed to reference sprites positions relative to each other quite often so it made sense to me.

If you want to go with option 1, I would suggest getting some NSLogs and printing out a point of the rect and the point you are comparing against and figure out what the different is.

Comment: Hi there, I'd love to go for option 1, but am not sure what point system my sprites are in and what systems are available. I'm just very confused about the functionality of the convertToNodeSpace methods...